# Reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 59 to the 15 allowed

Tags: java

I am working on a code logic. Based on the logic I have written below code, but I am getting sonar warning to reduce its complexity.
How can I refactor the below code to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 59 to the 15 allowed?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.getTotalCount(); i++) {
    listObj = (TariffRateGroupDTO) dataList.get(i);
    if (listObj != null && listObj.getTxnMode().equals("U")) {
        if (listObj.getFlightCondition() == null || listObj.getFlightCondition().isEmpty()) {
            TariffRateGroupDTO fc = getFlightCondition(listObj.getId(), listObj);
            flightCondition = fc.getFlightCondition();
            if (flightCondition != null) {
                ArrayList obj = (ArrayList) checkFlightCondition(flightCondition);
                if (obj != null && !obj.isEmpty()) {
                    ValidationException ve = new ValidationException();
                    ValidationError valError = (ValidationError) obj.get(0);
                    ve.setErrorCode(valError.getMessage() + " at row [" + (i+1) +"]");
                    throw ve;
                }
            }
        }else {
            flightCondition = listObj.getFlightCondition();
            if (flightCondition != null) {
                ArrayList obj = (ArrayList) checkFlightCondition(flightCondition);
                if (obj != null && !obj.isEmpty()) {
                    ValidationException ve = new ValidationException();
                    ValidationError valError = (ValidationError) obj.get(0);
                    ve.setErrorCode(valError.getMessage());
                    throw ve;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least for us on SO, you can reduce the cognitive complexity by properly formatting your code.

Comment: Split it into multiple smaller methods.

Comment: There is a **lot** of redundancy in that code. It feels like the logic wasn't thought through, and someone just kept on adding code. Also: generics have been around since Java 5. It might be about time to start using them.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is mostly about levels of nesting decisions, so try to reduce branches. But this code has more serious problems than that. Get rid of all the casts to `ArrayList` and the rawtypes first. Functions that return collections should never need to return `null` - return empty collections instead.

Comment: SideNote: For the future, try to configure your developement environment in a way that displays such metrics and other hints while you edit your code. For most static analyzers, there are plugins for many IDEs (e.g. sonarlint extension for eclipse, etc.) that allow that. That way, you are warned way before you get to a complexity of 59.

Answer (score 1):

This part of code is actually not so complex, probably you have something else in your class. You can read about cognitive complexity and how it counts [on the SonarQube website](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/white-papers/cognitive-complexity.html).

Here I give you some ideas about how to reduce the complexity of that piece of code (you can use them for other parts of code too):

- split code into multiple private methods
- private methods can be re-used for similar situations (eg., both parts inside `if (flightCondition != null)` can be replaced with one method which takes `ErrorCode` as a parameter)
- parts like `obj != null && !obj.isEmpty()` can be rewritten with some external libraries (in case of Apache Commons Collections, it can be done [like this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.util.Collection-): `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(obj)`
- `if (flightCondition != null)` can probably be moved into `checkFlightCondition()` method (if it fits with business logic)
- not quite relevant, but conditions like `listObj.getTxnMode().equals("U")` can often be flipped to `"U".equals(listObj.getTxnMode())` which will provide implicit nullsafe-check too.

P.S. I'm not saying anything about other problems in this piece of code (like others did in the comments) because it's not related to the question.